# How can I use GSON to parse and place into a list of objects?

Tags: java, gson

I have a domain object Foo, and I want to parse some JSON such as

```
[
    {"prop": "val"},
    {"prop": "val2"},
]
```

I want to get a `List<Foo>`. Something like this

```
List<Foo> foos = new Gson().fromJson(json, /*what goes here ?*/);
```

Comment: Are you still using JDK 1.4? [Type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) is since JDK 1.5

Comment: I dont even remember what I installed, but it was definitely within the last month. The compiler says 1.6

Comment: Well I used import java.lang.reflect.Type; which solves that problem. Now the second line gives an error saying I need to add SuppressWarnings which doesnt do anything

Comment: It is not an error, just a warning, ignore it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use a `TypeToken` to correctly express the type. `Class` is not sufficient in this case, because of the interaction with the generic type.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType();
List<Foo> projects = (List<Foo>) gson.fromJson(response, listType);
```

Comment: what if Project contains private fields and I have getter and setter methods. Will it still work? Does gson automatically look for the methods?

Comment: what you described is exactly how you should build your domain class, GSON takes care of everything from that point (getter and setter).

Comment: I get a bunch of errors with this code.. I must not be importing the correct libraries. Wants me to "Create method getType()". Now it's gone and it has something to do with Type

Comment: make sure you are using the latest jar file and check out the API [com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<T>](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/gson-1.7.1/docs/javadocs/index.html)

Comment: yep I've got the latest jars. I think the error has something to do with Type. Eclipse is simply not recognizing it